# Slow performance when adding dynamic error message to field title based on AngularJS watch over ngModel Controller Field Error

Tags: angularjs, performance, dynamic, message, validationerror

I have successfully used `$watch` over the form ngModel Controller `$error` attribute to watch for the invalid state then add custom error message to the HTML element tooltip (`title` attribute) when the validity state becomes invalid.

Following is the code:

```
var addValidationMessage = function (ngForm, elm, errAttr, errMsg, msgVar1) {
    //Use $timeout to ensure validation rules are added and compiled.
    //After compile is done then will start watching errors
    $timeout(function(){
        var elmModel;
        var ngModelName="";
        //Get the name of the 'ng-model' of the element being validated
        elmModel = angular.element(elm).controller('ngModel');
        if (elmModel && elmModel.$name) {
            ngModelName = elmModel.$name;
        }
        if (!ngModelName) {
            ngModelName = angular.element(elm).attr('ng-model');
        }
        if (ngModelName) {
            scope.$watch(ngForm.$name + '.' + ngModelName + '.$error.' + errAttr,
                function (newValue, oldValue){
                    //console.log("elm.id =", elm.id);
                    //The validation error message will be placed on the element 'title' attribute which will be the field 'tooltip'.
                    //newValue == true means there is error
                    if (newValue) {
                        var msgVar1Val;
                        //Perform variable substitution if required to get the final text of the error message.
                        if (msgVar1) {
                            msgVar1Val = scope.$eval(angular.element(elm).attr(msgVar1));
                            errMsg = errMsg.format(msgVar1Val);
                        }
                        //Append the error to the title if neeeded
                        if (elm.title) {
                            elm.title += " ";
                        } else {
                            elm.title = "";
                        }
                        elm.title += errMsg;
                    } else {
                        //Remove the error if valid.
                        //child.removeAttribute('title');
                        if (elm.title) {
                            //Replace the error message with blank.
                            elm.title = elm.title.replace(errMsg, "").trim();
                        }
                    }
                });
        } else {
            //console.warn("Warning in addValidationMessage() for element ID '%s' in ngForm '%s'. Message: 'ng-model' is not defined.", elm.id, ngForm.$name)
        }
    }, 1000);       
}
```

And, the above function is used within the element directive as follows:

```
errMsg = "Number of characters entered should not exceed '{0}' characters.";
addValidationMessage(ngForm, child, 'maxlength', errMsg, 'ng-maxlength');
```

The above code is causing performance issues when processing 1000+ fields. In other words, it causes the execution in Chrome to slow down by 10 seconds for 1000+ fields. In IE it causes processing to slow down by 1 minute.

The prupose

Is there better approach to achieve the same objective?

Appreciate your feedback.

Tarek

Comment: you have forms with 1000+ fields?  that in itself seems excessive, and would have noticeable performance implications even before trying to `$watch` every single one of them again (angular automatically watches anything with `ng-model`).

Comment: I know the proper approach is to use paging, but for now I need to see if there is better approach for the above required functionality.

Comment: For the time being, I disabled Dynamic Error Message for `maxlength` validation rule. And, to disable dynamic field highlight if the maxlength is invalid, I used HTML5 `maxlength` instead of `ng-maxlength` as the first one will prevent the user from entering more characters than allowed. With this changed, I saved 10 seconds in Chrome and 50 seconds in IE11.